# docker run -t doesn't let me run commands

Tags: docker

I'm starting to create a Dockerfile & have followed some simple tutorials like [containerize an application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) to find some starting commands. I'm just starting developing so I'd like to actually run commands on a docker ubuntu image so I can figure out where files go, what I should be running, etc.. until I've finished developing the Dockerfile.

My workstream so far has been:

```
docker build -t my-docker folder-with-dockerfile
docker run -t my-docker
```

My Dockerfile is currently based off `FROM ubuntu:latest`.

with `-t` to keep the image in the foreground to keep the container running, since I'm not actually starting a server process or anything yet. This starts the container and exposes a command line output like:

```
root@7f6bc4ce3f13:~#
```

but typing commands doesn't do anything. I can ctrl-c, which just displays another command prompt but doesn't actually quit. How can I run commands?

So far I've tried:

- If I run with -d instead, it runs in the background & quits immediately.
- I can open another terminal & run commands via `docker exec happy-running-container ls`, that works, but it's rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker run -it my-docker` runs in interactive mode with a terminal. The -i passes in my std input as I was hoping.

Reading the commandline reference for `docker run` suggests this -it combination as a good way to run with an interactive terminal:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/#interactive

Now that I'm running an ubuntu shell, `exit` even works to leave the shell (& stop the container running).

Comment: If the only thing your container is running is an interactive shell, then causing the shell to exit (`exit` built-in, `^D` usually) should cause the container to exit as well.